# Algorithm for this format

Tags: algorithm, formula

I am trying to develop a program to compute the tax for a given base salary, I believe given the format of the income tax table that I have, there should be a formula or algorithm to calculate the tax for a given base salary. Below is the sample format of income tax table. I can do lookups but I think an algorithm or formula might be the best approach.

```
Annual Salary   Monthly From    Ranges To   Tax Due
 18,000.00       0.00            1,500.00    0.00
 18,060.00       1,500.01        1,505.00    0.25 
 18,120.00       1,505.01        1,510.00    0.50 
 18,180.00       1,510.01        1,515.00    0.75 
 18,240.00       1,515.01        1,520.00    1.00 
 .....
 27,960.00       2,325.01        2,330.00    41.50 --last line of first format

 28,020.00       2,330.01        2,335.00    41.83 -- start of second format
 28,080.00       2,335.01        2,340.00    42.33 
 28,140.00       2,340.01        2,345.00    42.83
```

I was able to find a formula for the first part and its working find in my program but I can't make the second part work.

The formula for the first part is below :

The tax is 0.25 on every 5.00 or portion above 1500. So I am using

```
Ceil((monthly−1500)/5) * 0.25
```

I have tried similar methods for the second pattern but its not working so far

Comment: Under the assumption that this tax table is likely to change thresholds every year or so, I would not encode the current structure and values. I would instead run through the table backwards until I found the entry that had a range-to of more than the salary, then lookup the tax

Comment: Are you saying that you want 0.25 to be added for every 5 up to 1500, and then 1/4th of everything above 1500 should be added? For instance, 800 would be 800/5*0.25 = 40. 1800 = 1500/5*0.25 + 300*0.25 = 75 + 75 = 150 ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That you have to ask for that clarification sums up what's wrong with this approach. The current tax table may have two sections. Next years might have one, or four, or a non-linear tax increase per band, or some other change. I think seeking to produce an algorithmic answer adds nothing but inflexibility, and I'll eat my hat if there's any performance reason not to do the lookup.

Comment: @Paul this tax table might not change for sometime. Also don't you think this might be computationally expensive if the file has millions of line.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 0.25 have to be added to every 5 up to 2330. Less than or equal to 1500 has no tax. I don't seems to get your example.

Comment: I misunderstood this sentence: *The tax is 0.25 on every 5.00 **or** portion above 1500*.

Comment: @fanbondi, taxes change, in my experience. I don't believe any realistic tax regime will have a line per $5 up to $5 million.  And anyway, a better lookup will reduce the look up time to something trivial (See Andrey's answer)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, thereby providing a neat example of why we (as fallible humans) shouldn't try to re-interpret a specification already defined precisely for us in the lookup table.

Comment: Seriously, if someone came to me with a design that says "I'll try to convert this lookup table in a manual way to something that should be equivalent, I'd tell them to go away and try again". You'd be better to write something that read the table and generated your algorithm for you (Andrey's linear fit). That way, you can have more confidence it's correct.

Comment: So reading the lookup table and getting the corresponding tax would be the best approach in such cases @Paul.

Comment: In my opinion, yes. Or write the program to build the algorithm from the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just want to offset it by some number, specifically `41.33`.

```
41.33 + Ceil((monthly − 2330) / 5) * 0.5
```

Although this seems like a better solution: (considering that it might be the least effort to deal with new versions of it)

- Reading the data in in some automated way
- Doing a binary search for the range the salary falls under
- Look up the tax due

Comment: For now this is what I will go with. If the tax table changes then I would have to change this algorithm. I think its the same with the lookup method I would have to update the lookup table when ever the table changes.

Comment: " I would have to update the lookup table when ever the table changes." No, you wouldn't. As Dukeling has said, you read it in some automated way when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

A fully automated algorithm:

1. [linear fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fit) of the salary/tax table;
2. [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) for the exact value.